# How to let user change text font and colour in WordPress WSIWYG text editor

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have set up a WordPress website for a client and have found that the user cannot:

1) change font size

2) change the actual font

3) change colour of the font

for the text they enter in the WordPress admin section as there are no tools to do this in the WSIWYG text editor.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this, I have tried looking for a plugin that enables this but can't seem to find one.

Of course they can achieve this in the Text section through HTML but the users are not familiar with HTML and CSS and frankly I wouldn't want them doing that.

I am using the latest version of WordPress (3.9.2)

p.s. I have the [TinyMCE Advanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) plugin installed already, it's quite cool but it doesn't have the above features I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe It or Not ***you can do this*** with TinyMCE Advanced.

step 1.) Install and activate the plugin (you said that you done that)

step 2.) Navigate to Settings->TinyMCE Advanced (in admin back-end and **click it**)

step 3.) There you will see it says **Unused Buttons** click the button you want and

**drag and drop it** inside **Editor Settings** (above **Unused Buttons**).

step 4.) after you have drag and dropped buttons click **Save**

step 5.) in order to change **font color** ***hover over*** icons inside **Edit post**

on one of them (**beside undo/redo button**) you will see on hover tool-tip that says **Toolbar Toggle**

click it and it will expand TinyMCE

step 6.) beside **emoticons icon** you will see an **A** letter (that letter is

**underlined**) this is where you change text color.

As you can see there a lot of options to choose from (you probably want **Font Family** and **Font Sizes** **just see the step3** )

Comment: Wow! I would have never have found this out. Works great. Thanks